# Swift 4 SprikeKit - Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift

I am just learning Swift and I am following along with another project that I had worked on. However, I am getting this error:

Error I am getting:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

All my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var scoreLabel : SKLabelNode?
    var player : SKSpriteNode?
    var track : Int = 0

    var trackArray : [SKSpriteNode]? = [SKSpriteNode]()
    var ballDirection = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
    var velocityArray = [Int]()
    var playerVelocity : Int = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 100)

    var currentScore : Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.scoreLabel?.text = "SCORE: \(self.currentScore)"
        }
    }


    func createHUD() {
        scoreLabel = self.childNode(withName: "score") as? SKLabelNode
        currentScore = 0
    }

    //I think the problem is coming from this function, however I more-or-less copied it from a tutorial project that works so I don't know what the problem is.
    func setupTracks() {
        for i in  {
            if let track = self.childNode(withName: "\(i)") as? SKSpriteNode {
                trackArray?.append(track)
                print(track)
            }
        }
    }


    func createBall() {

        player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball1")
        player?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player!.size.width / 2)
        player?.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

        //This line throws the error
        let ballPosition = trackArray?[track].position
        print(track)
        player?.position = CGPoint(x: (ballPosition?.x)!, y: (ballPosition?.y)!)

        player?.position.x = (ballPosition!.x)
        player?.position.y = (ballPosition!.y)

        self.addChild(player!)

    }


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        createHUD()
        createBall()

    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

    }
}
```

I have 8 Color Sprite objects that I put in through the GameScene.sks each named 0 - 9,

I think it is looking for a value in the array that has not been yet assigned? but I have a part that (I think) is assigning that value. It also works in the other project so I am very lost.

Comment: Which line is giving the error?  (If you don't know, set a breakpoint and step through the code one line at a time.)  Use the debugger to examine arrays to make sure they contain what you expect.

Comment: it highlights this line `guard let enemyPosition = trackArray?[track].position else {return nil}`

Comment: As an aside....  It's usually a bad idea to have parallel arrays (i.e. multiple arrays that you expect to have the same number of elements and that you index using the same variable).  Better is to have some custom object with track, direction, and velocity properties and one array of those things.

Comment: What is the value of `track` and the size of `trackArray` when it stops?

Comment: I tried adding a print statement in that function to show it in the console and it does print anything... However, I did get this: `Unable to load custom class 'GameScene' from module '(null)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this doesn't make 100% sense to me without context, but based on what I can infer it seems a better solution for you would be to use a single dictionary to access the `SKSpriteNode` as well as the direction and velocity.  To achieve this you could create a custom object, or just use a simple tuple.

After you initialize the dictionary and fill it with the objects you can access a single value in the dictionary to get all of the data you need for your `createEnemy` function.  It might look something like this:

```
var tracks = [Int : (node: SKSpriteNode, direction: CGFloat, velocity: CGFloat)]()

func setupTrack() {
    for i in 0 ... 9 {
        if let track = self.childNode(withName: "\(i)") as? SKSpriteNode {
            //Get direction and velocity here, if initial value is known
            //Setting to 0 for now
            tracks[i] = (node: track, direction: 0, velocity: 0)
        }
    }
}


func createEnemy(forTrack track: Int) -> SKShapeNode? {
    guard let thisTrack = tracks[track] else { return nil }

    let enemySprite = SKShapeNode()
    enemySprite.name = "ENEMY"

    enemySprite.path = CGPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 20, height: 20), cornerWidth: 10, cornerHeight: 10, transform: nil)

    let enemyPosition = thisTrack.node.position

    let left = thisTrack.direction

    enemySprite.position.x = left ? -50 : self.size.height + 50
    enemySprite.position.y = enemyPosition.y

    enemySprite.physicsBody?.velocity = left ? CGVector(dx: thisTrack.velocity, dy: 0) : CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -thisTrack.velocity)

    return enemySprite
}
```

This will prevent you from going out of bounds on your array.  Note on this: Since you are looping through a hardcoded 0...9 range, but you are *optionally* appending items to that `Array` (in the case where your `if let track` fails) you have no guarantee that the "track" item with the name "7" corresponds to the 7th index in your array.  This is another reason a `Dictionary` is safer.  Additionally, it seems you are maintaining 3 separate arrays (tracks, directionArray, and velocityArray), which seems prone to error for the same reason I just described.

Comment: This gives 3 errors: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`, `Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Int' and 'CGFloat'`, `'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Bool'`

Comment: Yeah, you need to post a lot more code for me to know what’s going on. I was just guessing types based on your variable names. I was really only wanting to demonstrate the overall process - you should be able to fine tune to fit your needs.

Comment: What code do you need to see, it's not that much should I post all of it? Sorry I'm just starting out with Swift and I'm beyond lost...

Comment: Oh, no problem! Just post all the code for that file - that way I can see what type `left` is, for example.

Comment: And put comments in where the errors are being thrown - that’d help a lot too.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated it will all the code, it's a little different than what you saw before because after I couldn't even get anything to show up in the view I changed it from an `SK Shape` to an `SK Sprite` to use a picture instead of `CG` stuff. But it is the same exact error on the same line and everything.

Comment: Where are you calling `setupTracks`?

Comment: Stupid mistake, I just wasn't calling the function `setupTracks`. Thank you for the help